# Killing a terminal-attached process that doesn't respond to SIGINT, SIGQUIT

Tags: linux, unix

Sometimes both `Ctr-C` (SIGINT) and `Ctrl-\` (SIGQUIT) are too weak. Is there a way to do an more aggressive kill (e.g. kill -9) on the currently-attached process using a quick keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Well, if you want to go nuclear, alt-sysrq-i sends SIGKILL to all processes except init...

Comment: A bit less aggressive would be sending SIGTERM to all processes before, by doing Alt-SysRq-E ...

Comment: shouldn't this be a superuser-question? see [this](http://superuser.com/q/288772) and [this](http://superuser.com/q/243460)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with a specific command not responding to CTRL-C (because it ignores SIGINT, *or* because it asked the terminal driver to no longer recognise it as an interrupt character) , you can try wrapping it in `rlwrap`:

```
rlwrap -a -I <command>
```

`rlwrap` will catch the SIGINT sent by the terminal driver when you press CTRL-C and send a SIGTERM to `<command>` instead.

Of course, `<command>` may catch, or even ignore SIGTERM as well, but many commands that ignore SIGINT will respond to SIGTERM - while still being able to clean up before they terminate, in contrast to what happens when you use SIGKILL (`kill -9`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a `zsh` user, you can send `SIGTERM` with this in `.zshrc`

```
function terminate-current-job() { kill -s TERM %+ ; }
zle -N terminate-current-job terminate-current-job
bindkey "^T" terminate-current-job
```

That binds <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to the previously defined widget/function.

Comment: This works, but only for terminating background jobs. CTRL-C is used to interrupt the current *foreground* job.

Answer (score 0):

Like proposed in the other answers, you can try to kill the process by catching some other signal. This can be also done with the linux bash built in [trap command](https://linuxhint.com/bash_trap_command/)

> that is used to execute a command when the shell receives any signal

To KILL your executable if SIGINT (CTRL-C) is captured, you need to start it like this:

```
yourexecutable & pid=$! ; trap 'echo KILL ; kill -9 $pid' INT ; echo WAIT $pid ; wait $pid ; echo DONE
```

Note that the echos are just for debugging purposes, they can simply be removed if you don't need them.